# java reading constants in java servlet by storing all constants in seperate file

Tags: java

I have to set certain constants in file to use them in servlet for fetching data in database.what is the best way to use this resource files?
As spring will read properties files , how to make it in servlet to read constant values from file to make it use in java class?

Comment: configure a properties file in spring and inject it into your servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class to read a [.properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

You can populate the .properties file as a normal text file with entries in the format key=value per line.

You can place it in your filesystem and read it using an absolute path, like:

```
//full path:
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file"));
```

You can also place it in your web project's META-INF or WEB-INF folder so it will be loaded in the project's classloader when deployed. In this scenario you can read it without knowing its absolute path with the following commands:

```
//relative path in Classloader:
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties");
prop.load(in);
in.close();
```

Once loaded, you can then read the properties entries with:

```
props.getProperty("propName");
```

Comment: What is the location for properties file to place in project and how to give path for it?

Comment: In your project [it is recommended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) to place it in a folder named META-INF. You can create it if it doesn't exist since it is an optional folder in java projects. To load this file in a Properties use the example below the `//relative path in Classloader:` code comment